# Unresolved reference в мультимодульном проекте

Tags: android, gradle

Решил разбить проект на фичемодули. Использую gradle KTS. Создал директорию base в которой будут базовые модули (core, network...).

В settings.gradle.kts инициализирую core модуль и указывают путь.

```
include(":core")
project(":core").projectDir = File(rootDir, "/base/core")
```

В app build.gradle подключаю core.

```
 implementation(project(":core"))
```

Пробую в app модуле получить сущность из core. 
Код MainActivity

```
package ru.suhov.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import ru.test.core.entity.Entity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity)

        val entity = Entity("name")
        val name = entity.name

    }
}
```

Android Studio видит импорт, но на этапе компиляции получаю

```
e: C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\Test\app\src\main\kotlin\ru\suhov\test\MainActivity.kt: (5, 11): Unresolved reference: test
e: C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\Test\app\src\main\kotlin\ru\suhov\test\MainActivity.kt: (15, 22): Unresolved reference: Entity
```

Если использовать gradle без KTS, то все норм компилируется.Что я делаю не так?